# How do I send a uniform matrix to a shader in Haskell?

Tags: opengl, haskell, shader, vertices

Trying to do essentially do matrix multiplication on vertices in shaders for transformations and it's uh, not having it.

At the moment, I've got this:

```
curMatrix <- get ((matrix $ Just $ Modelview 0)::StateVar(GLmatrix GLfloat))
       mc <- getMatrixComponents ColumnMajor curMatrix
setUniform p "uModelViewMatrix" mc
```

setUniform being a function in the GLUtil package. Do I need to convert my array to a Vec4 (Vec4), or is there another way?

Thanks!

Edit:

I've ended up doing this:

```
getMat :: [GLfloat] -> [V4 GLfloat]
getMat (a11:a12:a13:a14: 
        a21:a22:a23:a24:
        a31:a32:a33:a34:
        a41:a42:a43:a44:_) = [(V4 a11 a12 a13 a14),
                              (V4 a21 a22 a23 a24),
                              (V4 a31 a32 a33 a34),
                              (V4 a41 a42 a43 a44)]
```

And uh, well that doesn't seem to have worked!

Edit 2: What I mean by it didn't work is, that I got it to set it as a uniform variable, but now my object has disappeared!

Comment: I think you're transposing the matrix. GL wants column major.

Comment: I specify column major when I get the matrix components, aren't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working! Main reason it wasn't working is because I wasn't using the projection matrix as well.

Please don't beat me with sticks for my bad/confusing variable names.

```
    mvMatrix <- get ((matrix $ Just $ Modelview 0)::StateVar(GLmatrix GLfloat))
    pMatrix <- get ((matrix $ Just Projection)::StateVar(GLmatrix GLfloat))
    mv <- getMatrixComponents ColumnMajor mvMatrix
    pm <-   getMatrixComponents ColumnMajor pMatrix
    let mvm = getMat mv
    let pM = getMat pm 
    let mvmp = mvm !*! pM
    setUniform p "uModelViewMatrix" mvmp
```

My getMat function is as:

```
getMat :: [GLfloat] -> V4 (V4 GLfloat)
getMat (a11:a12:a13:a14: 
            a21:a22:a23:a24:
            a31:a32:a33:a34:
            a41:a42:a43:a44:_) = V4 (V4 a11 a12 a13 a14)
             (V4 a21 a22 a23 a24)
             (V4 a31 a32 a33 a34)
             (V4 a41 a42 a43 a44)
```

I'm using the Linear package. The `!*!` infix function is a matrix multiplication.

This works exactly as I wanted it to, so yay! Hope it helps anyone else!

Answer (score 0):

Haskell's OpenGL bindings (currently 2.11.1.0) don't expose a function for uniform matrix values. This has been reported multiple times on the bug tracker:

- https://github.com/haskell-opengl/OpenGL/issues/68
- https://github.com/haskell-opengl/OpenGL/issues/33
- https://github.com/haskell-opengl/OpenGL/issues/14

That being said, if you have a datatype that satisfies an instance of type `Storable`, such as the `M44 Float` type from [ekmett/linear](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear), you can just use the raw pointer to the proper OpenGLRaw bindings call. [See an example here](https://github.com/Mokosha/Lambency/blob/master/lib/Lambency/Shader.hs#L61).

Comment: Is there another way to use transformation matrices in the shaders, then? As I understand it, the built in names for them have been deprecated.